# How to call same method for a list of objects?

Tags: python

Suppose code like this:

```
class Base:
    def start(self):
        pass
    def stop(self)
        pass

class A(Base):
    def start(self):
        ... do something for A
    def stop(self)
        .... do something for A

class B(Base):
    def start(self):

    def stop(self):

a1 = A(); a2 = A()
b1 = B(); b2 = B()

all = [a1, b1, b2, a2,.....]
```

Now I want to call methods start and stop (maybe also others) for each object in the list all. Is there any elegant way for doing this except of writing a bunch of functions like

```
def start_all(all):
    for item in all:
        item.start()

def stop_all(all):
```

Comment: a bunch of function is two function?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but there's no obvious reason in your example why you need that base class. Python will be very happy to let you have a list of unrelated objects and so long as they all have 'start' and 'stop' methods you can still iterate through them calling the methods.

Comment: Your defining `Base` with useless methods and then defining behaviour in `A` and `B` reflects a poor design in Python. Rather than using an abstract base class, you can just define `A` and `B` and use them interchangeably insofar as they share an interface. Your current way of doing things creates a useless class, which is just extra stuff you don't need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *_all() functions are so simple that for a few methods I'd just write the functions. If you have lots of identical functions, you can write a generic function:

```
def apply_on_all(seq, method, *args, **kwargs):
    for obj in seq:
         getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or create a function factory:

```
def create_all_applier(method, doc=None):
    def on_all(seq, *args, **kwargs):
        for obj in seq:
            getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwargs)
    on_all.__doc__ = doc
    return on_all

start_all = create_all_applier('start', "Start all instances")
stop_all = create_all_applier('stop', "Stop all instances")
...
```

Comment: This doesn't strike me as simpler than writing the for loop directly.

Answer (score 201):

**This will work**

```
all = [a1, b1, b2, a2,.....]

map(lambda x: x.start(),all)
```

simple example

```
all = ["MILK","BREAD","EGGS"]
map(lambda x:x.lower(),all)
>>>['milk','bread','eggs']
```

and in python3

```
all = ["MILK","BREAD","EGGS"]
list(map(lambda x:x.lower(),all))
>>>['milk','bread','eggs']
```

Comment: In Python 3 map returns a map object, not a list like in Python 2.  I'm not sure of standard procedure, but I thought I should correct it, so I submitted an edit.  So the code should now work as expected and correctly in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Also this feels like the more Pythonic answer, it should be the accepted one.  map is a good choice, and I've never used lambdas before now, so thanks.

Comment: haven't used python 3 much, but a more general solution shouldn't hurt  (and I dont' think it makes the example any less clear). Actually I haven't had a chance to work with python as much as I'd like over the past year.

Comment: In Python 3 `map()` function call will be not enough. It will create a generator object but wont apply lambda on each list element. Lambda will be applied on iterating through the map() result. `list(map(...))` will fix the problem.

Comment: @dreikanter or just do `[x.start() for x in all]`?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x:x.lower(),all))`

Comment: Using a list and then throwing it away strikes me as un-Pythonic. Because the invoked method is imperative code with side effects, an explicit `for` loop is more idiomatic and less surprising to the reader. If you really must, you could write `def foreach(fun, gen): for i in gen: fun(gen)`.

Comment: Does this guarantee elements in the list will be returned in the same order?

Comment: @Thomas for some reason, the for loop method works in my case but not the map method. And I don't use the generated list so it is, indeed, gross. But I just call a function on each same class objects of an object list that return nothing, so...

Comment: @Welgriv Check the comments above yours. As of Python 3, `map` returns a generator, so it's evaluating lazily (and in your case, that means not at all).

Answer (score 42):

It seems like there would be a more Pythonic way of doing this, but I haven't found it yet.

I use "map" sometimes if I'm calling the same function (not a method) on a bunch of objects:

```
map(do_something, a_list_of_objects)
```

This replaces a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
 do_something(a)
 do_something(b)
 do_something(c)
 ...
```

But can also be achieved with a pedestrian "for" loop:

```
  for obj in a_list_of_objects:
       do_something(obj)
```

The downside is that a) you're creating a list as a return value from "map" that's just being throw out and b) it might be more confusing that just the simple loop variant.

You could also use a list comprehension, but that's a bit abusive as well (once again, creating a throw-away list):

```
  [ do_something(x) for x in a_list_of_objects ]
```

For methods, I suppose either of these would work (with the same reservations):

```
map(lambda x: x.method_call(), a_list_of_objects)
```

or

```
[ x.method_call() for x in a_list_of_objects ]
```

So, in reality, I think the pedestrian (yet effective) "for" loop is probably your best bet.

Comment: My first reaction was map(lambda x: x.member(), list). It felt like a pretty clear one liner

Comment: Good conclusion about the "pedestrian" for loop. If this were CL you'd have `mapcar` and `mapc` to distinguish between the "want a list/throw away list" cases. But alas...

Answer (score 29):

The approach

```
for item in all:
    item.start()
```

is simple, easy, readable, and concise. This is the main approach Python provides for this operation. You can certainly encapsulate it in a function if that helps something. Defining a special function for this for general use is likely to be less clear than just writing out the for loop.

Answer (score 7):

maybe `map`, but since you don't want to make a list, you can write your own...

```
def call_for_all(f, seq):
    for i in seq:
        f(i)
```

then you can do:

```
call_for_all(lamda x: x.start(), all)
call_for_all(lamda x: x.stop(), all)
```

by the way, all is a built in function, don't overwrite it ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Starting in Python 2.6 there is a [operator.methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) function.

So you can get something more elegant (and fast):

```
from operator import methodcaller

map(methodcaller('method_name'), list_of_objects)
```

Comment: What is the best approach for python3?

Comment: @Neil this works in python3, the only different is that `map` returns an iterator in 3, not a list

Answer (score 4):

Taking @Ants Aasmas answer one step further, you can create a wrapper that takes any method call and forwards it to all elements of a given list:

```
class AllOf:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements = elements
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def on_all(*args, **kwargs):
            for obj in self.elements:
                getattr(obj, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
        return on_all
```

That class can then be used like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val="quux!"):
        self.val = val
    def foo(self):
        print "foo: " + self.val

a = [ Foo("foo"), Foo("bar"), Foo()]
AllOf(a).foo()
```

Which produces the following output:

```
foo: foo
foo: bar
foo: quux!
```

With some work and ingenuity it could probably be enhanced to handle attributes as well (returning a list of attribute values).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a generic function while avoiding referring to method name using strings, you can write something like that:

```
def apply_on_all(seq, method, *args, **kwargs):
    for obj in seq:
         getattr(obj, method.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)

# to call:
apply_on_all(all, A.start)
```

Similar to other answers but has the advantage of only using explicit attribute lookup (i.e. `A.start`). This can eliminate refactoring errors, i.e. it's easy to rename the `start` method and forget to change the strings that refer to this method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, in my opinion, depends on whether you need the result of the method and whether your method takes any arguments except `self`.

- If you don't need the result, I would simply write a `for` loop:

```
for instance in lst:
    instance.start()
```

- If you need the result, but method takes no arguments, I would use `map`:

```
strs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lower_strs = list(map(str.lower, strs))  # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

- And finally, if you need the result and method does take some arguments, list comprehension would work great:

```
strs = ['aq', 'bq', 'cq']
qx_strs = [i.replace('q', 'x') for i in strs]  # ['ax', 'bx', 'cx']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised no one has mentioned it so far, but if a one-liner is what you're after, Python *does* permit for-loops on one line:

```py
for i in ['a','b','c']: print( i.upper() )
```

Granted, this obviously does not follow your typical Python syntax, but in some scenarios you might actually want multiple loops like these close together for a bit more concise code, where it would make a lot of sense. E.g.:

```py
for e in checkboxes: e.click()
for e in text_inputs: e.send_keys('test')
for e in selects: e.select(0)
```

Unlike list substitutions, this also prevents unnecessary use of memory if you don't actually need to create a list.