# Is there a way to loop through methods and changing objects names?

Tags: python

I have a method that needs to be called on a lot of objects, and the code is getting extremely long because of that. I want to have a way of looping through objects names so the number of lines will be reduced.

```
c1.front_turn_clock()
c2.front_turn_clock()
c3.front_turn_clock()
c4.front_turn_clock()
c6.front_turn_clock()
c7.front_turn_clock()
c8.front_turn_clock()
c9.front_turn_clock()
c10.front_turn_clock()
c11.front_turn_clock()
c13.front_turn_clock()
c14.front_turn_clock()
c15.front_turn_clock()
c16.front_turn_clock()
c17.front_turn_clock()
c19.front_turn_clock()
c20.front_turn_clock()
c21.front_turn_clock()
c23.front_turn_clock()
c25.front_turn_clock()
```

The fix should look something like this:

```
while x <= 25:
   cx.front_turn_clock()
   x += 1
```

Comment: You should put all the objects in a list and operate on the contents of that list.

Comment: ok I'll try that

Comment: For example: `for obj in obj_list: obj.front_turn_clock()`

Comment: Relevant: [How to call same method for a list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682012/how-to-call-same-method-for-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make the code more expandable and smaller by making a list of objects

```
clocks = []
clocks.append(newclockobj)
...
for i in range(len(clocks)):
    clocks[i].front_turn_clock()
```

Also you can use enumerate instead of range(len())
or your original While idea

Comment: thanks, mate I don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: Using `for i in range(len(clocks))` is an _anti-pattern_ in Python. Something like `for clock in clocks:` would be better (because it's simpler and faster).

Comment: `for i in range(len(clocks)):` ... In Python, The canonical way to iterate over items in a list is to iterate over the items: `for clock in clocks:...` If you also need to know the item's index in the list use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 1):

Put c1-c25 in a list, then loop through each item and call front_turn_clock() on them

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this but the closest thing to what you want is probably `eval` which takes your string literal and executes it as if it's code.

```
while x <= 25:
   eval('c%i.front_turn_clock()'%i)
   x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the objects in a list and traverse the list.

```
for object in objects:
  object.front_turn_clock()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    globals()['c'+str(i)].front_turn_clock()
```

Or like this:

```
import sys

thismdl = sys.modules[__name__]
getattr(thismdl, 'c'+str(i)).front_turn_clock()
```

Both ways will try to get the instance at memory and execute the function.

I don't recommend though, using lists is more pythonic.